# How to get the week before the current week?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to compare the week number of a started task with the week before the current one.

```
and to_char(t.plan_start_dttm, 'YYYY-IW') = to_char(sysdate-1, 'YYYY-IW')
```

So yesterday, it was working fine, I got all records of last week. But today, I get the ones of this week.
So apparently, my "sysdate -1 is not the right way to do it.
Thank you

Comment: what you are doing, for ex: current day is Saturday, `sysdate-1` will return Friday (yesterday of Saturday). So if you like to go back one week, it should be `sysdate-7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yesterday, it was working fine, I got all records of last week.

Yesterday was Monday of this week; so subtracting one day would be Sunday of last week and truncating to the start of the week would be Monday of last week.

Today is Tuesday; so subtracting one day would be Monday of this week and then truncating to the start of the week would still be this week.

Instead, subtract an entire week's worth of days (7):

```sql
and t.plan_start_dttm >= TRUNC( sysdate - 7, 'IW')
and t_plan_start_dttm <  TRUNC( sysdate, 'IW' )
```

and if you compare on a range then Oracle can use an index on the `plan_start_dttm` column; whereas if you use `TO_CHAR` or `TRUNC` on the column then the column index cannot be used and you would need a separate function-based index.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 7 days instead of 1.  Or 1 week.  I also prefer `trunc()`:

```
trunc(t.plan_start_dttm, 'IW') = trunc(sysdate - interval '7' day, 'IW')
```

There is no need to convert to strings for this purpose.

Comment: `ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>` The syntax is `INTERVAL '7' DAY` with the units outside the quotes; however, `WEEK` is not a valid unit for either a `DAY TO SECOND` interval or a `YEAR TO MONTH` interval.

Comment: MT0 is right, the "week" is not working but the "day" is working. Thank to both of you anyway.

Comment: So I'm having a little issue. It works fine but gives me the results from mondays to sundays, and I need the week to start on sunday and end on saturday.